# Shift from print to tablet

Tags: pdf, html

Ten years ago, most people either read scienfitic papers on the screen or printed them on paper.

Today, I have the impression that printing becomes rare and people prefer tablet computers (often iPads) for that. If this trend continues, naturally the question arises if creating A4 (or letter) PDF documents is still the right way to go. This is especially true if you see that A4 paper is

1. usually much larger than the typcial tablet screen
2. not a good fit for either one column or two columns of text

On the other hand, just converting a document to HTML usually means that you loose a lot of the typesetting quality of LaTeX.

Are there good approaches to handle this?

Comment: Not really (yet), far as I can tell, apart from the obvious (HTML/CSS + images for formulae etc.) There is project by the name of “HINT” which works on reflowing TEX output, but it's early days. (Cf. https://www.tug.org/practicaltex2018/slides/ruckert.pdf)

Comment: @Ingmar  hint is in texlive 2022, (although mosly for tsting rather than production code, still)

Comment: My opinion: If you need a separate reader and file format, it will probably not succeed.